# Show that a point is a midpoint of a side of a triangle

Tags: triangles, plane-geometry

In $\Delta ABC$, the bisector of $\angle A$ intersects $BC$ at $D$. The perpendicular to $AD$ from $B$ intersects $AD$ at $E$. The line through $E$ parallel to $AC$ intersects $BC$ at $G$, and $AB$ at $H$.

Prove that $H$ is the mid-point of $AB$.

I have no idea on how to prove this question. Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: In such a type of problems, a good strategy may be to proceed backwards. In other words, you could consider the line $GH$ through the midpoints of $BC$ and $AB$ (which is parallel to $CA$ from Thales) and to prove that it intersects the bisector of $\angle A$ at a point, which sees $B$ perpendicularly...

Comment: Hint: Use that $AE$ (where $E = GH \cap AD$) is both the bisector of $\angle A$ and the median of $BB'$ where $B' = BE \cap BC$ within $\triangle ABB'$ => ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trivial by picture:

[image]

$BEA$ is a right triangle and by Thales' theorem $\widehat{BGH}=\widehat{BCA}$, $\widehat{BHG}=\widehat{BAC}$.
Angle chasing gives $\widehat{HEA}=\widehat{EAC}=\widehat{HAE}$, hence $HA=HB=HE$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT :

We have $\angle{HAE}=\angle{HEA}$, so $\triangle{HAE}$ is an isosceles triangle with $HA=HE$.

Now prove that $\triangle{HBE}$ is an isosceles triangle with $HB=HE$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha = \frac12 \angle CAB$. We have $\alpha = \angle AEH$ (alternate interior angles), so $\triangle AEH$ is isosceles of vertex $H$, so $HA = HE$.

Let $\beta = \angle HBE$, $\gamma = \angle EBD$ and $\theta = \angle EDG$. We have:

$$\beta + \gamma = \pi- (\angle ACB + 2 \alpha) = \pi - \angle EGD - 2\alpha = \pi - (\pi - (\alpha + \theta)) - 2\alpha = \theta - \alpha = (\pi - \angle EDB)  - \alpha = \pi - (\pi/2 - \gamma) - \alpha = \pi/2 + \gamma - \alpha$$

Hence, $\beta = \pi/2 - \alpha = \angle HEB$, so $\triangle HEB$ is isosceles of vertex $H$ and $HE = HB$.

Therefore, $HB = HA$

Answer (score 2):

We need to consider only the triangle $ABE$ with the point $H$ on $AB$ such that $\angle HEB=\angle EAC=\angle BAE=\theta$. We have $\angle BHE=2\theta$ and $\angle BEH=\frac12\pi-\theta$; so $\angle HBE=\frac12\pi-\theta$. Hence triangle $BHE$ is isosceles, as is $EHA$, with $|HB|=|HE|=|HA|.$